# Get max() value from distinct row value sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select max value for different rows by same column:

Here's my table

```
id          | visited_count
------------+--------------
01071400005 | 1
01071400005 | 5
01071400006 | 1
01071400006 | 3
```

I need to show 01071400005 and 01071400006, so I tried below code but it only selects 01071400005.

```
SELECT  MAX(visited_count) - 1 
from   tbl_all_purple_flag_level where id in 
(select distinct(id) from tbl_all_purple_flag_level )
```

How can I select both of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, then you just want to *group* your table by `id`:

```
SELECT id, MAX(visited_count) FROM tbl_all_purple_flag_level GROUP BY id
```